# Error when trying to modify and display a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have created the following array in main:

```
int arrayOne[40][60];
```

I am trying to do two things with it:

1. modify its contents by using a function that does this
2. displaying the array that has been modified

This may seem basic, however, I seem to be getting error messages.

I am trying to display my array using this:

```
void disArray(int [][60]);    // function prototype

disArray(arrayOne);      //function call in main

/*Actual function I use below */
void disArray(int diArray[][60]) {
    for (int r = 10; r < 30; c++) {
        for (int c = 10; c < 50; r++) {
            cout << diArray[r][c] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I'd expect this to display zeros but that isn't the case. However, I get a number that is repeated over hundreds of times in my display (its the same number too so its not showing addresses of each array point).

The second issue I'm having is that I also need to modify the contents of the array by passing it to a function.  I've tried doing this:

```
int *pArrayOne;   //declared in main
pArrayOne = &arrayOne[0][0];   //assigned in main

void modArray(int*);    //function prototype

modArray(pArrayOne);   //function call

//I'm trying to change the values of the first three cells of the first row to 8
void modArray(int *pOne) {        
    *pOne = 8;
    pOne++;
    *pOne = 8;
    pOne++;
    *pOne = 8;
}
```

It doesn't seem to be working, however...

If someone could teach how to display an array of that size and modify it selectively then that would be great!  (Please don't mark this as answered elsewhere because I have already looked at many other posts & they don't really help...this would take less than 5 minutes to answer for someone who knows arrays well)

Comment: Is `arrayOne` a local variable, i.e. is it declared inside another function? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, including the actual declaration of the array in relation to other code.

Comment: arrayOne is a local variable declared inside int main()

Comment: @stilLearning Please post a [MCVE] to get help diagnosing your errors.

Comment: You haven't declared variable `r`

Comment: sorry, this is my second time using stackOverflow... I put as much code as I thought was necessary but perhaps I may have put too much.  However, that shouldn't stop someone from answering the question I hope.  Next time I'll try to follow the appropriate guidelines.  Thank you though.

Comment: @stilLearning _"this would take less than 5 minutes to answer for someone who knows arrays well"_ Why do you think this is relevant? The relevance is how your question should be helpful for future research. We're not your personal helpdesk. Put more efforts on research before asking here please.

Comment: @SelçukCihan that was a typo... fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Local non-static variables are not initialized, their contents is *indeterminate*. Attempting to use them except to initialize them (for example to print their values) leads to *undefined behavior*.

If you want to initialize the array to all zeros then you need to explicitly do it:

```
int arrayOne[40][60] = { 0 };
```

---

To modify it in a function, you do it as usual:

```
void setElement(int array[][60], size_t row, size_t col, int value)
{
    array[row][col] = value;
}

...

setElement(arrayOne, 10, 20, 123);
```

The above code assigns the value `123` to `arrayOne[10][20]`.

Comment: how would I modify the contents of the array?

Comment: @stilLearning Just assign to the element you want to modify? Each element in the matrix could be considered a simple variable. See e.g. the example function I've added in my answer. And the indexes of course doesn't need to be literal value, they could be variables as well, as shown